# PHP En una función como retornar varios registros desde un arreglo

Tags: array

Tengo el siguiente script que realiza una consulta a una tabla en Postgres. La consulta me retorna los valores de unas coordenedas y los pone en un arreglo. Necesito hacer el retorno de esos cuatro valores separados por comas desde la función. Estos registros son las coordenadas de un extent para un mapa. La dificultad que tengo es que al verificar el retorno de la variable $arrayext; se muestran los valores pero con la palabra Array al final.

```
<?php
 function getCoord()
{
  $id = $_POST['id']; //Parámetro que viene de un script en ajax
  $conexion = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=atlas_2014 user=postgres 
    password=*******";
  $conn = pg_connect($conexion);

  $query = "SELECT x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max FROM extensiones WHERE 
   cod_unisecc = '$id'";
  $result = pg_query($conn, $query);
  $rowext = pg_num_rows($result);

  for($x=0; $x < $rowext; $x++)
  {
    $arrayext = pg_fetch_array($result,$x); 
    $arrayext['x_min'];
    $arrayext['y_min'];
    $arrayext['x_max'];
    $arrayext['y_max']; 
  }
   return $arrayext;
}
 echo getCoord();
?>
```

Cuando ejecuto el script en chrome esta es la salida:
-77.127652,5.418853,-74.242224,8.873977Array

Al hacer la depuración esto es lo que muestra:
[image: resultado de la depuracion]

Answer (score 0):

puedes retornarlo como un json, si lo estas capturando con javascript via ajax 
seria asi:

```
echo json_encode(getCoord());
```

Comment: Un cordial saludo. Gracias por la respuesta. Seguiré la recomendación de seguridad la cual es bien importante. Con respecto a la función pg_fetch_assoc aunque si sabía que existe nunca la había utilizado, voy a ajustar el código. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo, no sé si sabes que existe una función `pg_fetch_assoc` la cual se encarga de crearte un array asociativo a partir del conjunto de resultados. Su uso simplificaría tu código.

Te propondré una solución basada en esta posibilidad. Y corrigiendo además un grave fallo de seguridad, al no usar consultas preparadas.

```
<?php
 function getCoord()
{
    /*Usamos un ternario para evaluar lo que hay en el id*/
    $id = (empty($_POST['id'])) ? NULL: $_POST['id']; //Parámetro que viene de un script en ajax
    if($id){
        $conexion = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=atlas_2014 user=postgres 
            password=*******";
        $conn = pg_connect($conexion);
        /*Cambiamos el datos por un marcador, de ese modo neutralizamos la inyección*/
        $query = "SELECT x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max FROM extensiones WHERE cod_unisecc = $1";
        /*Preparamos la consulta y pasamos el valor $id de forma segura*/
        $result = pg_prepare($conn, "select_coord", $query);
        $result = pg_execute($conn, "select_coord", array($id));

        if ($result){
            /*Llenamos $arrResult usando datos asociativos*/
            while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $arrResult[]=$row;
            }
        }else{
            $arrResult["error"]="Error en la consulta"; 
        }
    }else{
        $arrResult["error"]="No se postearon datos para el ID"; 
    }
return $arrResult;
}

/*Es muy importante indicar el header en estos casos*/
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo json_encode(getCoord());
?>
```

Para más detalles sugiero que revises estas funciones en el Manual de PHP:

- [`pg_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php)
- [`pg_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-prepare.php)
- [`pg_execute`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-execute.php)